# What is the single most influential book every beer enthusiast should read?

Tags: brewing, taste, storage, serving

If you could go back in time and tell yourself to read a specific book about beer, which book would it be?

Comment: While beer is inherently a subjective matter and we should give leeway in the questions here, this feels like an altogether subjective question.  I can see this being rephrased to cover a certain ground or topic, but answer a question this broad will certainly differ from many people's, and there isn't really a "correct" answer.

Comment: I must, unfortunately, agree.  We have some leeway in constructing the rules of our little Stack Exchange, but on of the high-level rules for all SEs is to avoid opinion questions like "what's your favorite book on X."

Comment: As an addendum, I'd love to chat about exactly this topic on the beer.SE [chat] room with anyone interested.  :)

Answer (score 4):

[Tasting Beer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1603420894) by Randy Mosher is by far the most valuable beer book I've ever read.  It covers the styles you'll encounter, the flavors, the technology, the history, the science, and more.  I was a fairly knowledgeable beer enthusiast when I read it, but I wish I'd read it ten years earlier.  If I had, it would have increased my enjoyment of getting to know beer ten-fold by increasing my  understanding of what I was drinking.